# Can I use AWS Route53 registered domain in another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Haven't seen something like this (Hosted zone transfer maybe?), so I'll try here.

I have a pretty straightforward question, so I am hoping that someone can answer it or has any experience with the same case.

I have registered the domain using Route53 DNS service on one AWS account. I would like to use that registered domain on another AWS account, using it primarily for creating CNAME records for the load balancers. I have updated the NS records for the domain to match the second AWS account NS records and I am able to use and created hosted zone in that second account, but the CNAME or @ records are not resolvable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can sometimes be tricky so I am going to cover the initial steps.

1. You create a new hosted zone in Account B
2. You add that hosted zones NS record in Account A. This is a new NS record in the master record (mydomain.com)
3. You then add an alias for your load balancer on your hosted zone in Account B.

It looks like you are doing all of this so a few other things you can check:

1. The security group associated with your ELB allow port 80 or 443.
2. The public subnets associated with your ELB have routes to the internet gateway.
3. The NACLs on your subnets allow port 80 or 443.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to convey with *"This is a new NS record in the master record."* But you should never change or add to the NS records at the apex of a Route 53 hosted zone.  The only exception to this is if you are doing white label DNS which isn't under consideration, here.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done. However, I am able to reach resources (e.g. web page) using ELB default CNAME, but it won't work with the alias that I have created in the hosted zone.